# Javascript code does not work on web hosting server

Tags: javascript, hosting

I have one very strange problem. Javascript code on my web page does not work properly. The strange thing is that when I run the page on localhost (wamp) everything works perfectly, as it should. The problem starts when I upload web page to web hosting, one part of the code does not work. The part that should call pop up windows (div tags) does not work at all. When link is clicked nothing happens.

I have tried using two different free web hosts and same problem occurred on both. I also tried running developer tools (F12), but there are no errors as I expected because everything works perfectly on localhost.
Here is the particular code that does not work.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn">T1</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn2">T2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn3">T3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn4">T4</a>
</div>

<script>    
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); 
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");   
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];     
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
<script> 
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');   
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");   
  var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];     
  btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
  }     
  span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }    
</script>
<script> 
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');
  var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");    
  var span3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];     
  btn3.onclick = function() {
    modal3.style.display = "block";
  }
  span3.onclick = function() {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }    
</script>
<script>    
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('myModal4');    
  var btn4 = document.getElementById("myBtn4");    
  var span4 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[3];       
  btn4.onclick = function() {
    modal4.style.display = "block";
  }  
  span4.onclick = function() {
    modal4.style.display = "none";
  }   
</script>
```

I understand that javascript is the front-end technology and that it does not run on the server, but I really do not know what causes this. I hope someone had similar problem since I really have no idea what could it be.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help we'll need a little more from you. You said: _Here is the particular code that does not work._ : There is no element with `id` of `myModal` (et.al.), there is no element with a class name of `close` included here. If your code is designed to show or hide these other elements, it would be helpful to see how they are structured. Please provide the rest of the structure.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Here is the first modal content. Let's focus on that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="date_filter.php">
 <h1>Enter dates</h1>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start" placeholder="Enter start Date" required>
 <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="end" placeholder="Enter end Date" required>
 <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Enter">
 </form>
  </div>

</div>

Comment: @Ricky97 do you have four modals declared in your HTML. Also why so much script?

Comment: @Bibberty Yes, of course I have 4 modals declared. Each script is for one modal. I just do not get it why it does not work when hosted. Everything is fine on localhost

Comment: It could be that you `DOM` is not ready when your code executes. Remember when hosted things are not instant.

Comment: @Bibberty What would be the best way to check that?

Comment: use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { **YOUR CODE HERE**});` this will ensure your code executes when the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify a lot of the code if we use `functions` and pass some parameters.

also, we can use **Event Delegation** instead of adding listeners to each object, this is very effective for dynamic `HTML` and repetitive element structures.

Notice how we test the `event.target` using a `matches`.

I have dummied up the Modal for the demo.

```js
// First lets use a functions
const showModal = (modalId) => {
  const modal = document.querySelector(`#${modalId}`);
  modal.style.display = 'block';
};

const hideModal = (modalId) => {
  const modal = document.querySelector(`#${modalId}`);
  modal.style.display = 'none'; 
};

// Now lets listen for any click
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Based on what was clicked we will do something.
  if(e.target.matches('.showmodal')) showModal(e.target.dataset.modal);
  
  if(e.target.matches('.close')) hideModal(e.target.parentNode.id);

});
```

```css
.modal {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: none;
}

span.close {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times</a>
     <a href="#" id="myBtn" class="showmodal" data-modal="myModal">T1</a>
     <a href="#" id="myBtn2" class="showmodal" data-modal="myModal2">T2</a>
  <a href="#" id="myBtn3" class="showmodal" data-modal="myModal3">T3</a>
  <a href="#" id="myBtn4" class="showmodal" data-modal="myModal4">T4</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">Modal 1 <span class="close">Close Me</span></div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">Modal 2 <span class="close">Close Me</span></div>
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">Modal 3 <span class="close">Close Me</span></div>
<div id="myModal4" class="modal">Modal 4 <span class="close">Close Me</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most problem is created by functions like `window.onload=function()`. If there is another Javascript that has the same thing coded then they will both wait for each other till eternity.

***Just add the javascript to the bottom of the website i.e after the body.***

You must be putting the code on the `head` and the website can not see the element `myModal2`.